# syntax error using redshift listagg function

Tags: amazon-redshift

```
select id, listagg(timestamp,',') 
within group (order by timestamp) as timestamp 
from activity group by contact_id order by contact_id limit 1;
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: select eloqua_contact_id, listagg(timestamp,',') within grou...
```

Anything wrong with this query? When i remove the delimiter option i do not get an error and everything returns fine. How do i add commas to separate the list agg column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the issue is the column name "timestamp" as that is a data type and reserved word.  If you enclose the column name in double quotes it will keep it from being interpreted as a datatype.  (best guess)

```
select id, listagg("timestamp",',') 
within group (order by "timestamp") as "timestamp" 
from activity group by contact_id order by contact_id limit 1;
```

Generally not a good idea to name your columns the same as datatypes.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly it! I appreciate you pointing out the tip for not naming columns the same as datatypes :) accepted this answer.